# Selenium pull HREF out of TD in table

Tags: python, html, selenium, pandas

I'm reading a table from a web page and one of the columns has a link in it. The table is something like this

```
<table id="GridView1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            ...
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><a href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank">Link</a></td>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am reading this as a pandas Dataframe (version 0.16.0) and in the column with the link it just says the word "Link" and I would like to have the actual link in the href.

If there isn't an easy way to get this through pandas, is there another way to simply get the link and fill it in manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't know the link text(s) beforehand and giving the HTML structure what you've provided, we can write a CSS selector:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#GridView1 tbody tr td:nth-child(2) a")
```

And then get the `href` via `get_attribute()`:

```
print([link.get_attribute("href") for link in links])
```

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you'd have to know which row and column the child is in, and loop through each of them one by one to get them separately?

Comment: @dlwlrma, alecxe's selector will traverse through each row and column, and cherry pick all of the `<a>`'s that are inside of each `2`nd column.  according to your html, it's probably safe to assume that all the `<a>`s will be nested in the `2`nd td, so i'd say this is a safe solution

Comment: Thanks. And it is a guessing game - there is no complete HTML, there is no code, there is no desired result posted in the question. I've answered under the assumptions, cannot do better with what is provided.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your help. I came up with my solution from your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to the solution @alecxe came up with, but what I find is much clearer. Assuming you have the table id and you only want the links within that table, the following will give you the href links in the table and adds it as a column to your dataframe.

```
table = browser.find_element_by_id(table_id)
df = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'), header=0)[0]
links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')]
df['links'] = links
```